# Trouble of finding matching values from a different workbook excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have this excel files, this is what my data looks like in the first workbook, which could have 2000 + entries and in  a general format.

```
        A       
1     5001987
2     1458285
3     2506588
4     4745089
5     2540486
.
.
```

My other excel file looks like this, but also in a general, but the data within it is generated by something else which results of its output like this.

```
      A
1    ['2506588']
2    ['2540181']
3    ['2553486']
4    ['2540181']
5    ['2540389']
6    ['2553384']
```

On a specific column somewhere, i have written this function:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([outputbarcode.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$4,B2:B1992,2,TRUE),"Y","N")
```

I simply want it to look if excefile 2 cell A1 value exist in excelfile 1, print Y, if not, N.

Running the function above returns #N/A

Is there something wrong with my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On excel file 2, try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(MATCH(VALUE(MID(A1,3,7)), Sheet1!A:A, 0),)>0, "Y"), "N")
```

`Sheet1` is excel file 1 here. I prefer `index` & `match` to `vlookup`. You can [search why](https://www.google.com/search?q=index+match+vs+vlookup).

Comment: what does )>0,  at the end do?

Comment: If a match found, `index(match(...))` returns a value which is > 0. If you find difficulty in understanding nested formula, you can [check calculations step by step](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do an edit/replace and remove those odd characters permanently. Then you won't need the mid() function but the rest of @Sangbok lee answer will be fine and that may help with future operations.

Comment: Good point. Indeed if it were my work to do, I'd do that first.

Comment: You and me both !